# Invalid Version: android-4.2.2 error on appium

Tags: c#, appium

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in WebDriver.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Invalid Version: android-4.2.2.

Above is the error message which im getting when try to start the appium server.

Bellow is the logs on Appium.

How am i going to get rid of this?

```
[Appium] Creating new AndroidDriver (v1.37.0) session
[Appium] Capabilities:
[Appium]   browserName: 
[Appium]   version: 4.2.2
[Appium]   javascriptEnabled: true
[Appium]   deviceName: CB5A1THVTT
[Appium]   appActivity: com.XXXX
[Appium]   platformName: Android
[Appium]   autoWebview: true
[Appium]   sessionOverride: true
[Appium]   app: XXXXXXXXXX1_.apk
[Appium]   appPackage: XXXXXX
[Appium]   newCommandTimeout: 0
[Appium]   recreateChromeDriverSessions: true
[BaseDriver] Capability 'autoWebview' changed from string to boolean. This may cause unexpected behavior
[BaseDriver] Capability 'newCommandTimeout' changed from string ('0') to integer (0). This may cause unexpected behavior
[BaseDriver] The following capabilities were provided, but are not recognized by appium: version, javascriptEnabled, sessionOverride.
[BaseDriver] Session created with session id: 44d14fbe-0919-47dd-81b0-7b0bf62924d6
[AndroidDriver] Getting Java version
[AndroidDriver] Java version is: 1.8.0_141
[ADB] Checking whether adb is present
[AndroidDriver] Shutting down Android driver
[AndroidDriver] Called deleteSession but bootstrap wasn't active
[MJSONWP] Encountered internal error running command: TypeError: Invalid Version: android-4.2.2
    at new SemVer (C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\Programs\appium-desktop\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\semver\semver.js:273:11)
    at compare (C:\Users\XXX.SL\AppData\Local\Programs\appium-desktop\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\semver\semver.js:460:10)
    at rcompare (C:\Users\XXX.SL\AppData\Local\Programs\appium-desktop\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\semver\semver.js:470:10)
    at Array.sort (native)
    at Array.sort (C:\Users\XXX.SL\AppData\Local\Programs\appium-desktop\resources\app\webpack:\~\core-js\modules\es6.array.sort.js:21:1)
    at ADB.callee$0$0$ (C:\Users\XXX.SL\AppData\Local\Programs\appium-desktop\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-adb\lib\tools\system-calls.js:89:17)
```

Comment: I manage to  get rid of this issue by installing  appium-desktop-Setup-1.2.0.exe .